# INTERSECT MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the intersection of several SQL requests. I tried a lot of commands but i'm still stuck.

Here are the 3 requests.

Anyone has an idea to help me ?

1

```
SELECT username
FROM mdl_user
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_grades
ON mdl_user.id=mdl_quiz_grades.userid
WHERE mdl_quiz_grades.quiz = 17;
```

2

```
SELECT username
FROM mdl_user
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_grades
ON mdl_user.id=mdl_quiz_grades.userid
WHERE mdl_quiz_grades.quiz = 16;
```

3

```
SELECT username
FROM mdl_user
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_grades
ON mdl_user.id=mdl_quiz_grades.userid
WHERE mdl_quiz_grades.quiz = 15;
```

Comment: Consider providing some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

INTERSECT can be easily rewritten using Joins:

```
SELECT t1.username
from 
 (
   SELECT username
   FROM mdl_user
   INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_grades
   ON mdl_user.id=mdl_quiz_grades.userid
   WHERE mdl_quiz_grades.quiz = 17
 ) as t1
join
 (
   SELECT username
   FROM mdl_user
   INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_grades
   ON mdl_user.id=mdl_quiz_grades.userid
   WHERE mdl_quiz_grades.quiz = 16
 ) as t
on t1.username = t2.username
join
 (
   SELECT username
   FROM mdl_user
   INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_grades
   ON mdl_user.id=mdl_quiz_grades.userid
   WHERE mdl_quiz_grades.quiz = 15
 ) as t3
on t1.username = t3.username
```

But in your case it's the almost the same query, just different WHERE-conditions. You can apply aggregate logic:

```
SELECT username
FROM mdl_user
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_grades
ON mdl_user.id=mdl_quiz_grades.userid
WHERE mdl_quiz_grades.quiz in (15,16,17)
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

If the same userid might have the same quiz multiple times you need to apply DISTINCT:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT quiz) = 3
```